# Menu de links e imagens com float

Tags: html, css

Tentei criar um menu com *html* e *css* sem nenhum framework, utilizei `float:left` para colocar a imagem com o logo a esquerda e resto das imagens que são ancoras deveriam ficar a direita mas ao utilizar  `float:right` não obtive o resultado esperado, poderiam me ajudar a identificar o problema?

Obs.: 
Não precisa ser com `float` é que essa foi a forma que tentei. Vale lembrar que o menu acompanha o scroll do site.

**Segue abaixo o código que tentei:**

```css
#wrap {
  width:calc(100% - 1px);
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

body a {
  text-decoration:none;
}

body img {
  border: none;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.menu img {
  float:left;
  margin: 15px 0px 0px 20px;
  height: 70%;
}

.menu .menu-link {
  float:right;
}


.menu .menu-link a {
  line-height: 100px;
  color: #00497e;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size: 11pt;
}

.menu .menu-link a:hover {
  border: 0;
  background-color: #e20613;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#">
      <img alt="Logo" src="http://inpartsaudebi.com.br/assets/img/brand-inpart.png">
    </a> 
    <div class="menu-link">
      <a href="#about" id="menuAbout">
        <img src="https://static.dentaldepartures.com/places/fa-building-o.png" style="width:5%;" />
        Empresa
      </a>
      <a href="#users" id="menuUser">
        <img src="http://alumnes.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/fa-user-circle-o-c0a2bd7a.png" style="width:5%;" />
        Usuário
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Meu objetivo era algo semelhante a isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esso está errado width:100%-1; tem que ser width:calc(100% - 1px); onde esta 1px pode ser qualquer medida REM, EM, %

Comment: Obrigado pela informação, alterei o código para calcular o `width`corretamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caique o seu código está muito bagunçado rss, então fiz um modelinho bem básico com algumas medidas em PX mesmo e com FlexBox para vc ter uma ideia.

```css
html, body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #666;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
img {
    max-height: 60px;
}
.logo {
    background-color: red;
    height: auto;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.direita {
    display: flex;
}
.item {
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;

}
.item a {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 80px;
    align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="#">
            <img alt="Logo" src="http://inpartsaudebi.com.br/assets/img/brand-inpart.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="direita">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#about" id="menuAbout">
                <img src="https://static.dentaldepartures.com/places/fa-building-o.png" /> Empresa
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#users" id="menuUser">
                <img src="http://alumnes.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/fa-user-circle-o-c0a2bd7a.png" /> Usuário
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Da uma estudada no código que vc vai ver que é bem tranquilo e funciona melhor que o Float.

**Agora um modelo com Float:Left e Float:Right pra vc entender o conceito melhor já que era sua primeira opção**

> **Manda exibir na tela inteira  *para não aparecer bugado no executar do snippet***

```css
html, body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.menu {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #666;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
.logo {
    float: left;
}
.logo a img {
    max-width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px;
}
.item {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px;
}
.conteudo {
    margin-top: 80px;
    height: 1000pxpx;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="#">
            <img alt="Logo" src="http://inpartsaudebi.com.br/assets/img/brand-inpart.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="direita">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#about" id="menuAbout">
                <img src="http://placecage.com/50/50" /> Empresa
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#users" id="menuUser">
                <img src="http://placecage.com/50/50" /> Usuário
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="conteudo">
    <p>conteúdo</p>
    <p>conteúdo</p>
    <p>conteúdo</p>
    <p>conteúdo</p>
    <p>conteúdo</p>
    <p>conteúdo</p>
    <p>conteúdo</p>
    <p>conteúdo</p>
    <p>conteúdo</p>
</div>
```

*Modelo bem simples também, só para fins didáticos*

Comment: Hugo, adaptei o código para trabalhar similar a sua resposta. Porém eu estou criando esse layout para o IE em modo de compatibilidade e acredito que a propriedade `display:flex;` não funciona como deveria. O menu quebrou em várias linhas.

Comment: Vou tentar com o float (sua resposta atualizou agora)